# Access SQL database on windows using linux terminal

Tags: 14.04, windows, mysql

I need to access a  SQL database (microsoft sql server)  on a windows machine (virtualized - windows 2008 r2) and retrieve some information from the tables. I'm using a linux terminal.

I know how i can list the information on the tables but i have no idea how to do the "connection". Can someone point me to what should i search for?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sqlcli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-cli) is the easiest method when you are used to the mysql command line.

From the link an example connection string:

```
mssql -s abcdef.database.windows.net 
-u username@abcdef -p thepassword -d mydatabase -e
```

You can install it using `npm`:

```
sudo apt install npm
npm install -g sql-cli
```

Comment: Ok @Rinzwind, i'll give a try :). Thanks for your time and your example.